# React + Redux binded state has no data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

After one of the Redux tutorials decided to implement that facny `action->reducer->store->view` chain for simple app with only login part.

Seems like all setted up but when I run my app - in `mapStateToProps(currentState)` no any sign of the any custom state fields which I expected to see! (default state from reducer). But the action function is fine, as you can see on the screenshot

[image]
[image]

I can't see whats wrong here so, decided to ask it.

So here is the code

So, first of all - `store.js`

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk));

    if (module.hot) {
        module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
            const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers');
            store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
        });
    }

    return store;
}
```

then `login` reducer

```
const initialState = {
    user: {
        name: '',
        password: ''
    },
    fetching: false
}

export default function login(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOGIN_REQUEST: {
            return { ...state, fetching: true }
        }
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS: {
            return { ...state, user: action.data, fetching: false }
        }
        case LOGIN_FAIL: {
            return { ...state, user: -1, fetching: false }
        }
        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
}
```

and the root (`reducers/index.js`):

```
import login from './login/login';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

export default combineReducers({
    login
});
```

the `action`

```
import {
    LOGIN_REQUEST,
    LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_FAIL
} from '../../constants/login.js';

export function onLoginAttempt(userData) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_REQUEST,
            user: userData
        })

        tryLogin(userData);
    }
};

function tryLogin(userData) {
    let url = 'SignIn/Login ';

    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.post(url, userData)
            .then((response) => dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                data: response.data
            })).error((response) => dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_FAIL,
                error: response.error
            }))
    }
};
```

So here is entrance point:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './containers/app.js';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';

let store = createStore(configureStore);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("content")
);
```

and here is the `app.js` (Login is just sompe custom div with two fields nothing special)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Login from '../components/login/Login';
import * as pageActions from '../actions/login/login'


class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const { user, fetching } = this.props;
        const { onLoginAttempt } = this.props.pageActions;

        return <div>
            <Login name={user.name} password={user.password} fetching={fetching} onLoginAttempt={onLoginAttempt} />
        </div>
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(currentState) {
    return {
        user: currentState.user,
        fetching: currentState.fetching
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        pageActions: bindActionCreators(pageActions, dispatch)
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have state which looks like:

```
reduxState = {
   login: {
       user: {
         name: '',
         password: ''
       },
       fetching: false
   }
}
```

but then you try to access properties that don't exist.

```
function mapStateToProps(currentState) {
    return {
        user: currentState.user,
        fetching: currentState.fetching
    }
}
```

I think you need to:

```
function mapStateToProps(currentState) {
    return {
        user: currentState.login.user,
        fetching: currentState.login.fetching
    }
}
```

Comment: oh thank you! thats caused the problem, I missed such a simple thing!

Comment: @DanilGholtsman I made these kind of mistakes myself when I was learning redux :)

Comment: wellp, good to hear that, looks like it's not really fatal mistake then :)

Answer (score 1):

You have this line `let store = createStore(configureStore);` on your entry point. However, inside `configureStore`, you have a call to `createStore()`

Basically you're calling something like `createStore(createStore(reducers))`. That's probably the cause of the problem.

You should probably call it like

```
let store = configureStore( /* pass the initial state */ )
```

Comment: changed it like that :)

Comment: wellp, the first answer is helped. but I chnaged it liek that anyway, maybe it would prevent other problems, so I just put +1